# make a series in R with seq

Tags: r, seq

I try to generate a series like:
a thousand of 1, a thousand of 2,... until a thousand of 100.
I try this code:

```
 test <- round(seq(1, 100, length.out=100000))
```

but unfortunately, when I do a table, I obtain this:
[image]

Have you an idea?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry everyone,  I find => test <- rep(seq(1, 100), each=1000). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are using `round` which rounds to the nearest integer.

Just do `test <- seq(1, 100, length.out=100000)`

Comment: This produces the sequence 1 to 100, incrementing by 1/1001

Comment: Yes, that products float. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use:

```
test <- rep(1:100, each = 1000)
```

Comment: Thanks SmitM. It works.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is *replicate* and not *sequence*:

```
replicate(10, c(1,2,3))
```

will generate 10 sequences of {1,2,3}:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
[2,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
[3,]    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3     3
```

In your case, you would need:

```
replicate(1000, seq(1,100, by = 1))
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks Azim.